# Connecting to an API using Power Bi

Tags: api, powerbi

I am trying to connect to an API using Power BI. I am doing this by clicking on the Get Data then choosing Web, typing the URL address of the site. It comes with the list of API links created when I drill to any of them I cannot see anything. Is this the correct way of doing it? Many Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For querying REST APIs, that's the correct way of doing it yes. But in your case, it might be an issue with the API itself or that you need more details in the query? It's hard to troubleshoot without vieweing the API documentations.

If you then press on Advanced, you can then include further details for your request if needed.

I will include some screenshots below of how to choose the Web connector.

[image]

[image]